# can't receive data from android?

Tags: android, json, servlets

My servlet is not receiving the data from android client. No error or warning is shown in logs.My android screen shows something like tomcat error report in html format.How to retrieve data from android in servlet.My servlet returns null.How to check my servlet receiving data or not?

```
public boolean PostData() 
{
try {
    String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/myapp/StudentDetails"; 
    boolean isPosted;
    String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
    String classs = getIntent().getExtras().getString("classs");
    String age = getIntent().getExtras().getString("age");

    // creating default Client 
    HttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // Connect URL 
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(URL);
    HttpPost mpost = new HttpPost(sb.toString());
    List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuepairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(3);
    nameValuepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
    nameValuepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("classs",classs));
    nameValuepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age",age));
    mpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuepairs));
    HttpResponse responce = mClient.execute(mpost);
    HttpEntity entity = responce.getEntity();
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = buf.readLine()) != null) {
    sb1.append(line+"\n");
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sb1.toString()+"",1).show();
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(sb1.toString());

    isPosted = true;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    Log.w(" error ", e.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w(" error ", e.toString());
    }
    return false ;
    }
```

**Servlet coding**

```
     public class ClassDetails extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException
    {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String title = "Database Result";
    String docType =  "<!doctype html public \"-//w3c//dtd html 4.0 "  +"transitional//en\">\n";
    out.println(docType + "<html>\n" + "<head><title>" + title + "</title> </head>\n" + "<body bgcolor=\"#f0f0f0\">\n" +  "<h1 align=\"center\">" + title + " </h1>\n");

   String name = request.getParameter("name");
   String classs = request.getParameter("classs");
   String age = request.getParameter("age");
   if(sldept !=null)
   {
       out.println(" First: " + name + "<br>");
       out.println(" Last: " + classs + "<br>");
       out.println(" Last: " + age + "<br>");

   }
   else
   {
       out.println("no value");

      }   
    }
      }
```

Comment: Have you specified the `INTERNET` permission in the manifest?